# React native props,ref value is undefined inside keyboard hide event?

Tags: keyboard, react-native

i am trying to clear my Textinput focus inside keyboard hide event,but i am not able to get reference 
inside keyboard hide event method.i tried to print props value  it also getting undefined

```
constructor (props) {
    this.inputs = {};
}

_keyboardDidHide () {
   console.log("value"+this.props);
   this.inputs['inputValue'].blur();
    }

componentWillMount () {
   this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', this._keyboardDidHide);
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
   }

<TextInput
            ref={input => {
              this.inputs['inputValue'] = input;
            }}
            autoFocus={true}
            blurOnSubmit={false}
    />
```

let me know how to clear the TextInput focus on _keyboardDidHide method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do here, however I assume you want to at least get the info out from your input.

No need for that `ref` magic there though, just use simple react state changes.

```
class InputWrapper extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      input: ''
    };

    this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
  }

  handleInput(input) {
    this.setState({input});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TextInput onChangeText={this.handleInput} />
    );
  }
}
```

This will give you a TextInput Component with control over the input.
Now you should add a `componentDidUpdate` method as well, that prints out the current state, so you can observe what is happening when you change the input value.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  console.log(this.state);
}
```

As for bluring and such, you should definitely check out the documentation on `TextInput` : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html

Additionally, might I suggest to jump into the lifecycle documentation of react itself, plus checking up on `props` vs `state` in react. It is a confusing concept in the beginning and you should definitely revisit it.

---

As for blurring the input, simply do this:

```
  <TextInput
    ref={input => this.input = input}
  />
```

And then you can call:

```
  this.input.blur();
```

wherever you want.

Also, do not forget to bind your `_keyboardDidHide` callback within your constructor or when adding it as the listener callback, like so

`this._keyboardDidHide = this._keyboardDidHide.bind(this)`

`Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', this._keyboardDidHide.bind(this));`

Hope this helps

Comment: i want to clear focus of the text input inside key event